# Picking specific character and setting it into a var

Tags: python, string, if-statement, variables

I am trying to make a program that turns specific characters into numbers..
for example setting a to 51251
and b to 75414
and if you type 'ab' you get = 5125175414
I tried this:

```
a = '742461'
b = '634146'
c = '634174'
answer = '0'
en = input("Here:  ").lower()
while True:
    if en == 'a':
        answer1 = answer + a
        print("a")
    elif en == 'b':
        answer1 = answer + a 


    elif en == 'c':
        answer1 = answer + a
    
    elif en == 'done':
        print(f"{answer1}")
        
    else: 
        print("error")
```

But it doesn't work at all :/.
You guys have any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this will ask the user to input chars until he input done and will aggregate the value of the chars in to the answer

```
a = '742461'
b = '634146'
c = '634174'
answer = ''
while True:
    en = input("Here:  ").lower()
    if en == 'a':
        answer += a
        print("a")
    elif en == 'b':
        answer += b
    elif en == 'c':
        answer += c
    elif en == 'done':
        print(f"{answer}")
    else:
        print("error")
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the need to read input in every iteration of the loop, you’d usually use a dictionary for that:

```
values = {
    'a': '742461',
    'b': '634146',
    'c': '634174'
}

answer = '0'

while True:
    en = input().lower().strip()
    if en == 'done':
        break
    answer += values[en]

print(answer)
```

That way the code is much shorter and can be easily extended without having modify multiple parts of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You must take the input every iteration of the while loop and then process it, so `en = input("Here:  ").lower()` must be inside the `while True`. 'answer' is a string so no need to initialize it with '0'. So maybe something like this:

```
a = '742461'
b = '634146'
c = '634174'
answer = ''
while True:
    en = input("Here:  ").lower()
    if en == 'a':
        answer += a
    elif en == 'b':
        answer += b 
    elif en == 'c':
        answer += c
    elif en == 'done':
        print(answer)
        break
    else: 
        print("error")
```

Or better you can use dictionary like this:

```
d={
    'a':'742461',
    'b':'634146',
    'c':'634174'
    }
answer = ''
while True:
    en = input("Here:  ").lower()
    if en == 'done':
        print(answer)
        break
    if en not in d:
        print("error")
    answer+=d[en]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a better approach using dictionary like so:

```
maps = {'a': '742461', 'b': '634146', 'c': '634174'}

en = input("Here:  ").lower()
print(''.join([maps.get(e, '') for e in en]))
```

This takes input as a string (for ex: `'ab'`) and returns the desired output.